# Where to put preference based layout operations in ActionBarActivity

Tags: android, android-activity, sharedpreferences

In my app I am creating a custom preference screen. This screen in reached via mainActivity (launcher). The mainActivity also shows the current status of some of these settings by reading them and laying them on views. Now, when the user will reach one of the preference screens and edit them, by design I aim to bring him back to the mainActivity (it would be intuitive to press the back button). This time however I want to show the latest edited settings.

I am used to putting layout operations in onCreate. But, in this case onCreate will only be called once when the activity starts and read the status of preference settings and lay them on screen. However, when he will open a settings activity, edit them and press back button he will not see his latest settings laid on screen as onCreate need not be called.

So, on what activity callback should I place the operations to read preferences and lay them on views.

This is based on my understanding and I may have messed up big time. Guide me, Thanks...

Comment: I was thinking on using onResume for reading preferences and building Ui, but ActionBarActivity does not have that callback. Although, it has an onPostResume() and the docs says it "Dispatch onResume() to fragments.". Does this guarantee that it will be called everytime my activity comes in the foreground ? I am not using the fragment framework though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone looking for an answer. Its pretty basic stuff. Create function in your main activity to read preferences and update your views. Now, start your preference activity using `startActivityforResult()` and when result arrives from that activity, run the same function inside `onActivityResult()`. Done.